# Using sed, how could we cut a specific string from a line of text?

Tags: scripts, sed

Using `sed`, how could we cut a specific string from a line of text?

The string ->

```
Email subject: Test email one two
```

Expected response ->

```
test email one two
```

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you want all lower cases in your expected response or do you want to preserve the cases?

Comment: If any of the following posts answered your question please mark that post as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to convert everything to lowercase, using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^Email subject: \(.*\)/\L\1/' infile
```

`sed` command breakdown:

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: separates the command from the pattern
- `^`: matches the start of the line
- `Email subject:` matches a `Email subject:` string
- `\(.*\)`: matches and groups any number of any character
- `/`: separates the pattern from the replacement string
- `\L`: zero-width assertion which forces the following pattern to be printed lowercase
- `\1`: backreference which is replaced with the first capturing group

Comment: I think OP wants to get all the strings after `Email subject: ` . btw, I'm getting `Email subject: Test email one two` as the output with your solution.

Comment: @Ron In his example output `Expected response` doesn't show up, so I'm assuming he wants to cut the match there. However it works, my test was on a file containing only this line: `Email subject: Test email one two Expected response`

Comment: @kos Shouldn't the search be non-greedy. Emails can be large. Btw, this works (Rev 2).

Comment: @prakharsingh95 What do you mean? Are you expecting multiple `Expected response` strings to show up within the file?

Comment: @Ron Ah I see your point now. That's probably right, thanks.

Comment: Looking at questions' source I think I am thinking right.

Comment: @kos I thought OP wanted to extract something from middle of a string, which could have large strings after it. So I suggested a non-greedy approach. Cleared up now.

Comment: The redirection is unnecessary - `sed` accepts filenames as arguments.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I understand using `stdin` or arguments as a mere stylistic choice but maybe I'm wrong. Does it make a difference?

Comment: With `sed`, you wouldn't be able to use `-i` in-place editing. It's easier to have `sed` process multiple files when they are passed as arguments. Other utilities, on the other hand, (additionally) won't have access to the file's name or be able to seek inside the file.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Indeed. Ok, I've changed it

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, you want to extract from:

```
Email subject: Test email one two
```

only the 'actual' subject of the email:

```
test email one two
```

So the following will work:

```
sed "s/^Email subject: //" test.txt | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' > output.txt
```

- `test.txt` is the files containing your text.
- `output.txt` will contain only words that come after `Email subject:`
- `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]` converts all upper case letters to lower case letters

Comment: The `g` switch is not useful since you're matching a single instance, however the problem is that any uppercase "T" will be converted to a lowercase "t", changing potential intended capital "T"s in the subject.

Comment: Would make more sense than lowercasing just the first character tough.

Comment: No, I'm making all lower

Answer (score 1):

My two cents with `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/^Email subject: */,""); print tolower($_)}' \
    <<< "Email subject: Today's subject: watch out for delimiters"
```

*Output*

```
today's subject: watch out for delimiters
```

Comment: "`Email subject: Today's subject: watch out for delimiters!`" ;)

Comment: @kos better? =)

Comment: Very much better ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using pure `bash`:

```bsh
$ str='Email subject: Test email one two'

$ echo "${str#*: }"
Test email one two
```

If you want the first `T` as lowercase:

```bsh
$ str='Email subject: Test email one two'

$ echo "${str#*: }"
Test email one two

$ new="${str#*: }"

$ echo "${new,}"
test email one two
```

All in one:

```bsh
$ str='Email subject: Test email one two' && new="${str#*: }" && echo "${new,}"
test email one two
```

Here we have used [`bash`'s parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) feature.

- `"${str#*: }"` will get us `Test email one two` i.e. we are discarding from start to `:` followed by a space (`:`)
- `"${new,}"` will convert the first uppercase character to lowercase